# Scraping the comments section of a Web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the comments counter from a Web page. The code is presented below.

When I ask it to print `letters`, the output is an empty list. Why that is happening?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
r2 = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/01/03/steam-surpasses-12-million-concurrent-users").read()

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2)
letters = soup2.find_all("div",class_="fyre-comment-count")
print letters
```

Answer (score 3):

The list is empty because there *are* no comments on that page.  `div#livefyre-comment` is empty, and `div.fyre-comment-count` does not exist.

Up in the page's header, there is a suspicious `script` tag pulling JavaScript from `http://cdn.livefyre.com/Livefyre.js`.  I don't know what Livefyre is, but I assume it sucks comments out of a database somewhere and inserts them into `div#livefyre-comment` or its surrounding `div.article-comments`.  Presumably, `div.fyre-comment-count` will also appear somewhere in the DOM once the script is done.

This sort of... design decision is increasingly common on Web sites.  To see what a Web page *really* looks like, browse it with both JavaScript and cookies off (and be prepared for the occasional "500 Internal Server Error" from sites that never imagined such hooliganism was possible).

I don't know enough about screen scraping to tell you where to go from here.  You might be able to piece together a URL to fetch the comments (and their count) directly from Livefyre.  I'd start by perusing the JavaScript functions they provide, and the `data-settings` attribute of `div#livefyre-comment`, which appears to be a JSON dictionary full of relevant parameters.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is very close, almost right. You just missed a few things. Check the code below.

```
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
r2 = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ign.com/articles/2016/01/03/steam-surpasses-12-million-concurrent-users").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2, 'html.parser')
for line in soup.find_all("div",class_="fyre-comment-count"):
    comments = ''.join(line.find_all(text=True))
    print (comments)
```